# C# console application reading data from a file in plugged USB - Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, usb, readfile

I have a console application build in `.net Core` platform independent  that reads data from plugged USB, I tested with Windows works perfectly fine.

Now, I'm moving the console application to run on raspberry pi that runs Linux, but didnt read data from the plugged USB to raspberry pi.

I have mounted the USB in Linux but still didn't work. It can't find connected USB in Linux, here is my code that read data from USB:

```
 private static void ReadFromUSB()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine("Checking connected USB ... \n");
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                         .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                         .OrderBy(drive => drive.Name)
                         .Select(drive => drive.Name);

            if (drives.Count<string>() > 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected USB is found! \n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("Reading USB content ... \n");
                if (File.Exists(drives.First() + "\\file.txt"))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading file.txt file \n");
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(drives.First() + "\\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                    Data = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    Console.WriteLine("Data value: " + Data+ "\n");
                    sr.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Cant find file.txt file!\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("No USB is Connected! \n");
            }
        }
```

On the screen it prints `No USB is connected!`,

What I'm missing here ?

**Update**

How I mounted the usb in Linux:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /mnt/usb
sudo find /mnt/usb -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
ls -l /mnt/
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb/
ls /mnt/usb
```

Comment: How did you mount the USB?   USB devices and be different types like a file system or a serial device.  You may of mounted the USB incorrectly.

Comment: I updated my answer with how I mounted the USB, Is that the right way to do it ? @jdweng

Comment: See if following helps : https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO.html#toc10.5

Comment: I couldnt find what im looking for :/

Comment: A sda is a hard drive (originally a sci device) that connects to your machine on a USB cable.  Sometimes referred to as a removable hard drive.  Once mounted you read and write like any file in c#.  The communications uses a serial port and once mounted you access like a file system.  See : https://community.nxp.com/t5/Kinetis-Microcontrollers/Open-SDA-for-serial-communication/m-p/614783#M36548